# Dynamic array using malloc and realloc?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to collect input integers one by one. My array starts with size 1 and I want to expand it by 1, with every input collected (is this a smart thing to do?)

Anyway, this is the code I managed to come up with, but it's not working as intended.

After this process, sizeof(array) always returns 8, which I assume means that the array is only being resized once. (sizeof(int) is 4 bits)

Trying to output the array results in multiple instances of the first input variable.

**OUTPUT CODE**

```
for(int s=0;s<sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);s++){
    printf("%i\n",array[i]);
}
```

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
    int i;
    int size = 1;
    int *array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int position = 0;

    do{
        i = getchar() - 48;
        f (i != -16 && i != -38 && i != 0) {
            array[position] = i;

            position++;
            size++;
            *array = realloc(array, size * sizeof(int));
        }
    } while (i != 0);
```

**UPDATED STILL NOT WORKING CODE**

```
    int i;
    int size = 1;
    int *array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int position = 0;

    do{
        i = getchar() - 48;
        f (i != -16 && i != -38 && i != 0) {
            array[position] = i;

            position++;
            size++;
            array = realloc(array, size * sizeof(int));
        }
    } while (i != 0);
```

Comment: *"... but it's not working as intended. What's wrong with it?"* - you tell us.

Comment: What happens is when I loop through the resulting array, all values outputted are equal to the first input value. Additionally, sizeof(array) always returns 8, which means that the array isn't actually getting resized properly? If I start with size 1, and int = 4 bits, that somehow means that the resize is only happening once.. Any ideas?

Comment: Please put that explanation *in the question*. And please do not copy answers back into the question. Rolled back.

Comment: Updated with explanation of my problem...

Comment: Please see my previous comment. Correct the code you are using, not the faults in the question.

Comment: You're being extremely unhelpful and pedantic. I've updated my post for you. The change was 1 symbol, the other change was functionally identical code, just more readable.

Comment: Note that it is usually best to grow the array other than one element at a time.  A simple heuristic is to double the space each time you allocate more.  You have to keep track of the space allocated and the space used separately (two counters instead of one).  When the used counter reaches the allocated counter, double the amount of space allocated.  At the end, if there's enough space 'wasted' (allocated but not used), you can reallocate to shrink down to the size actually needed.

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, I'll probably end up doing that. But just to understand the problem I'm facing - what's wrong with the code I have here? Even if it's not a good idea to reallocate with every input, why doesn't this work?

Comment: `Trying to output the array` Show us how you're outputting it. You're storing characters in `int`s; I kind of doubt you're printing it right. `sizeof(array)` returns 8 because it equals `sizeof(int*)` which is 8 (you're probably compiling as 64-bit). `sizeof` doesn't work how you think for pointers to arrays.

Comment: I edited my post with the code I'm using to output the array. Though I'm sure the problem is with realloc or me using it incorrectly - in the end there's always only 2 elements in the array, regardless of input.

Comment: @Aldo Actually, you shouldn't be so sure. See my answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(With some copy-paste from my comment:) `sizeof(array)` returns 8 because it equals `sizeof(int*)` (`array` is type `int*`) which is 8 (you're probably compiling as 64-bit). `sizeof` doesn't work how you think for pointers to arrays.

Similarly, your output code is wrong, for the same reason. You only print the first two elements because `sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)` will always be `8/4=2`. It should be

```
for(int s=0;s<size;s++){
    printf("%i\n",array[s]);
}
```

(note also changed index variable `i` to `s`)
where `size` is the variable from your other code chunk(s). You cannot find the length of the array from `sizeof` if it's dynamically allocated with pointers; that's impossible. Your code must "remember" the size of your array.

Comment: For the love of... My error was intuitively using array[i] instead of array[s]... How did I not see that... Anyways thanks, I understand how to use sizeof correctly in this case, though research shows there's more nuances to it

Comment: @Aldo You understand how to use `sizeof`? It doesn't appear so at all. The size `8` comes from the fact that storing a pointer requires 64 bits with your compiler options; it has nothing to do with the number of elements in your array or even the fact that it's an array of `int`s (make them `double`s and see for yourself, still size `8`). In fact, your code will probably crash if your array contains only one element, because you always attempt to print exactly two elements (unless you change `sizeof(int)` to `sizeof(double)`, in which case it would be exactly one element).

Answer (score 4):

```
array = realloc(...)
```

not `*array`.  Per the [realloc docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html), `realloc` returns the pointer, which you can store directly in your `array` pointer.

**Edit** One thing that will make your life easier: use `char` constants instead of raw numbers.  E.g.,

```
i = getchar();
if(i != ' ' && i != '\n' && i != '0') {
 /*    48-16       48-38        48-0      right? */
    array[position] = i - '0';   /* '0' = 48 */
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing that jumps out at me: inside your loop, this line:

```
*array = realloc(array, size * sizeof(int));
```

should instead be:

```
array = realloc(array, size * sizeof(int));
```

In the original version, you were sticking the result of `realloc` in the first element of the array by dereferencing the pointer first. Without the asterisk, you're reassigning the array itself.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! This was an artefact from copy/pasting, I just tried changing array to array* to see what would happen at first. I corrected this now in my post. What happens is when I loop through the resulting array, all values outputted are equal to the first input value. Additionally, sizeof(array) always returns 8, which means that the array isn't actually getting resized properly? Any ideas? @Jonny Henly